# removing unused p tags

Tags: html, wordpress

I have the following code which puts < p > tags back on the paragraphs in my Wordpress post. (I removed the images and placed them later, uing this to put just the text)

```
  <p>
<?php
    $content = preg_replace('/(<img [^>]*>)/', '', get_the_content());
    $content = wpautop($content); // Add paragraph-tags
    $content = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content); // remove empty paragraphs
    echo $content;
?>
</p>
```

It works, and puts my paragraphs in p tags again, However it outputs empty < p > < /p > tags in between my actual paragraphs. I want to get rid of these empty paragraph tags

Comment: you are probably looking at the rendered output? you prob need to find p tags that your browser is auto closing rather then empty tag?, view source to see the html outputted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just overwriting the variable

Try this (notice `.=` instead of `=`) `.=` adds to the variable as opposed to overwriting it.

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<img [^>]*>)/', '', get_the_content());
$content .= wpautop($content); // Add paragraph-tags
$content .= str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content); // remove empty paragraphs
echo $content;
```

Comment: unfortunately that just copies the entire text twice and still has an empty p tag

Answer (score 0):

Use this function it will help you to remove this `<p></p>` tag

```
<?php echo get_the_content();?>
```